# Сохранение word2vec в текстовом формате

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, word2vec, gensim

Я пыталась сохранить модель word2vec в текстовом формате, но получила ошибку. Может кто-то может объяснить откуда возникают дубликаты и что такое "model.wv". Заранее спасибо

```
model = Word2Vec(all_words, min_count=3, sg = 1, size = 300 )
model.save_word2vec_format('test_w2v.txt', binary=False)
```

```
WARNING:gensim.models.base_any2vec:under 10 jobs per worker: consider setting a smaller `batch_words' for smoother alpha decay
Word2Vec(vocab=20, size=300, alpha=0.025)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/word2vec.py", line 26, in <module>
    model.save_word2vec_format('test_w2v.txt', binary=False)
  File "/word2vec.py", line 1307, in save_word2vec_format
    raise DeprecationWarning("Deprecated. Use model.wv.save_word2vec_format instead.")
DeprecationWarning: Deprecated. Use model.wv.save_word2vec_format instead.
```

Comment: А про какие дубликаты вы писали? В `model.wv`, `wv` является полем, у которого вы вызываете метод `save_word2vec_format`

Comment: спасибо... тоесть вызывать это поле нужно,чтоб записать модель в текстовом формате? О дупликате я имею ввиду эту часть предупреждения (DeprecationWarning: Deprecated. Use model.wv.save_word2vec_format instead)

Comment: Это не дубликат, а устаревшее. Дубликат -- Duplicate

Comment: большое спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка `DeprecationWarning` означает, что вызов метода `save_word2vec_format` напрямую из модели `model.save_word2vec_format` является устаревшим и нужно вызывать метод из поля модели `wv`:

```
DeprecationWarning: Deprecated. Use model.wv.save_word2vec_format instead.
```

Попробуйте так:

```
model = Word2Vec(all_words, min_count=3, sg=1, size=300)
model.wv.save_word2vec_format('test_w2v.txt', binary=False)
```